# JSON Deserialization to create a list

Tags: .net, json

I have an API call that returns the following:

```
"{\\\"isFailed\\\":false,\\\"result\\\":\\\"[{\\\\\\\"HOU\\\\\\\":2.00}, 
 {\\\\\\\"DAL\\\\\\\":5.00}]\\\",\\\"exceptionMessages\\\":null,\\\"sendMailTo\\\": 
 null,\\\"sendMail\\\":false,\\\"mailSubject\\\":null,\\\"mailBody\\\":null,\\\ 
 "Emails\\\":[]}"
```

I am able to deserialize to the point where I get all values.

I want to take the result field and go a step further.

`result = "[{\"HOU\":2.00},{\"DAL\":5.00}]"`

I want to take it further.. and be able to create a list in C# to insert

HOU 2
DAL 5

I am not sure how to proceed. Thank you.

Code is below:

```
public bool ValidateD365PriceResponse(string Response, ref List<InventoryDetailResponse> message)
        {
            string rawResponse = Response;
            try
            {
                D365Response response = new D365Response();
                ObjectConverter converter = new ObjectConverter();
                Response = Response.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
                Response = Response.Replace("\\\\\"", "\\\"");
                response = converter.JsonStringToObject<D365Response>(Response);
                if (!response.isFailed)
                {
                    message = converter.JsonStringToObject<List<InventoryDetailResponse>>(response.result);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogException(this.ToString(), "Error received from D365 while submitting price request. "
                        + response.exceptionMessages);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogException(this.ToString(), "Error received from D365 while parsing a successfull price request. "
                        + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: why so many escape characters? You could change result to a dynamic variable and then grab just the result obj. `dynamicvar.result[0]`

Comment: Which json library are you using? You should be able to view the list in message if isFailed was true but per your example json its false.